# Cannot use the "getSpotifyApi" function in spotify app

Tags: javascript, api, spotify

No matter what we try, every time I try to call the function "getSpotifyApi" it always returns:
"ReferenceError: getSpotifyApi is not defined"

I'm stumped on where to go from here because I can't do anything with spotify if it wont let me use its api...

All my javascript code is in  tags in the index.html of my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `getSpotifyApi`is not defined it is probably because you are using the 1.X API, which uses a different approach to include the frameworks. I would recommend you to have a look at the [Developer Guidelines](http://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/guidelines/developer/) which explains the basics on how to getting started.

There is also a [sample app on GitHub](https://github.com/spotify/apps-tutorial/tree/1.0) that you can use to see how the different available frameworks are used.

Comment: perfect! that was my problem, it wasn't very clear on the spotify documentation/online resources that there was that much of a difference between API's. There really needs to be some type of reference.