# Is it possible to use the default tabs with 1.X api

Tags: api, web-applications, spotify

I am using the "new" spotify apps api and their documentation about the default tabs only seem to be relevant if you are using the old 0.X api.

I can create the tabs with my manifest using the below code. But I can't seem to fin a way to interact with them.

```
"DefaultTabs": [
    {
        "arguments": "test",
        "title":  { "en": "test" }
    },
    {
        "arguments": "test2",
        "title": { "en": "test2" }
    }
]
```

I found a example of interacting with the default tabs that looks like this:

```
 sp = getSpotifyApi(1);
// detects arguments value for tab  
sp.core.addEventListener("argumentsChanged", function (event) {  
  console.log('args changed', sp.core.getArguments());      
});
```

But I keep getting the error message "Uncaught ReferenceError: getSpotifyApi is not defined " and according to this post [Cannot use the "getSpotifyApi" function in spotify app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15960631/cannot-use-the-getspotifyapi-function-in-spotify-app) it's due to the fact that it's the 0.X way of interacting with the api.

[Cannot use the "getSpotifyApi" function in spotify app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15960631/cannot-use-the-getspotifyapi-function-in-spotify-app)

The only thing close to it that i found where the 1.X tab bars, they dont resemble a classic spotify tab bar, more like regulair gray buttons.

https://developer.spotify.com/docs/apps/views/1.0/tabbar-tabbar.html

anyone have any ideas here?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your tabbar docs point to the proper usage documented on https://developer.spotify.com/docs/apps/views/1.0/ui-ui.html.  I think UI.setActiveView should do what you want.

Alternatively, you should be able to navigate using uri's like `spotify:app:appname:tabname`

*disclaimer* I haven't built any tabs into my app yet.

Comment: the part of the documentation you refere to handels with tabs, not default tabs. two different things.